# brand new toilet installed by plumber won't drain

Tags: toilet

Ok,  I have read many questions and answers to this question, but none of them are what mine is doing.  Buckets of water poured down don't go down, holes aren't clogged, all the guts in toilet work fine. I have logged it--sometimes I get 1 or 2 flushes that actually work, there has been a time I actually got 30 flushes. Sinks, tub, shower, other toilet all drain & work correctly with no bubbling, stink, etc. This toilet will fill to almost overflowing, then takes an hour to drain (no solids, minimal toilet paper). We have snaked with 3' and nothing. Only me here, no children or anything dropped in. A toilet is a simple fixture--people question its a defective toilet?! Venting? Pipe was cut in attic thinking vent issue and still nothing. Here's the plumbing: in crawl there is a 90 degree into a 45 degree, a 4' run with a 1/16" per foot slope (supposed to be 1/4" slope per foot), vent is 12' away from toilet before going upwards then reduced to 1 1/2" pvc, then 7-8' up in ceiling with six 90 degree elbows, about 12-15' run in attic and goes back to 2" pvc to meet an existing toilet, both vented out same pipe. Toilet is American Standard. Help?!

Comment: Have you checked with the plumber to see if they did everything OK?

Comment: If the toilet was installed by a plumber, then call out that plumber.  My guess is that you have a soft clog somewhere in the line.  If the toilet doesn't drain but the rest of the bathroom does, more likely than not the rest of the drains connect after the clog.  You may just need a longer snake.

Comment: When the bowl finally drains, does it stop at the normal level, or go down to almost empty?

Comment: Yes, checked with plumber. After 1 1/2 months of being clogged, he told me I didn't have a good plunger, he used his own and said it was plugged from toilet paper.  Unlikely, after that long, toilet paper would have broken down. Yes when bowl drains, it goes to almost empty. We are pulling toilet today to check wax ring, clog, and snaking.

Comment: We pulled toilet, wax ring ok, toilet ok. Plumber shimmed with 2 pennies!? Is this proper? We then dump 3 gallons of hot water in, water fills to top of drain.  Snaked it with 25' snake several times, nothing! Real mystery?!

Answer (score 1):

Your DIY answer is:
Call the plumber that installed it.

If that does not work, call your state licencing board, and determine who the bonding agent is for the plumber (it's a licenced plumber, right?)